# java - Hibernate map component with multiple arrays

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map three table columns in three primitive arrays. But whatever I try, I can't get this to work.
Here's the code:

```java
class Parent {
    private Component component;
}

class Component {
    private Parent parent;
    private int[] valuesOne;
    private int[] valuesTwo;
    private double[] valuesThree;
}
```

Hibernate mapping:

```xml
<class name="com.package.Parent" table="parent">
    <id name="id" column="id" access="field" type="int">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    ...
    <component name="component" access="field">
        <many-to-one name="parent" class="com.package.Parent" insert="false" update="false" fetch="join" column="id" access="field"/>
        <primitive-array name="valuesOne" table="component" access="field">
            <key column="parent_id"/>
            <index column="index"/>
            <element column="value_one" type="int"/>
        </primitive-array>
        <primitive-array name="valuesTwo" table="component" access="field">
            <key column="parent_id"/>
            <index column="index"/>
            <element column="value_two" type="int"/>
        </primitive-array>
        <primitive-array name="valuesThree" table="component" access="field">
            <key column="parent_id"/>
            <index column="index"/>
            <element column="value_three" type="double"/>
        </primitive-array>
    </component>
</class>
```

Database table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id              INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
)


CREATE TABLE component (
    id              INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    index           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value_one       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value_two       INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value_three     DECIMAL NOT NULL
)
```

Now this half works. Hibernate will create for each value to store a separate  query, like this:

```sql
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        component
        (parent_id, index, value_one) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
```

What I actually want is:

```sql
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        component
        (parent_id, index, value_one, value_two, value_three) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

How can I achieve this through Hibernate mapping?

Comment: I don't get it. In Java you have array of integers. But your CREATE TABLE has single integer. How exactly do you plan to map array into a single column? You should probably have multiple tables, one per array. Alternatively, you can store array of integers as a BLOB or something.

Comment: You're partially correct. I was just overthinking this I guess. I just needed to create an extra class and map that as an array inside the `Component` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was overthinking this, I just needed to create one array with multiple fields.

```java
class Component {
    private Parent parent;
    private ComponentEntry[] entries;
}

class ComponentEntry {
    private int id;
    private Component parent;
    private int valueOne;
    private int valueTwo;
    private double valueThree;
}
```

Then just map the array.

```xml
<array name="entries" table="component" cascade="all-delete-orphan" access="field">
    <key column="parent_id" not-null="true"/>
    <index column="index" type="int"/>
    <one-to-many class="ComponentEntry"/>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:
In order to implement bulk and batch inserts then need to configure the batch size in application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=5
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
```

Then you need to create an entity (model) for Component table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Component")
public class Component {
@Id
private String id;

@Column(name="value_one")
private int value_one;

@Column(name="value_two")
private int value_two;

@Column(name="value_three")
private double value_three;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getValue_one() {
    return value_one;
}

public void setValue_one(int value_one) {
    this.value_one = value_one;
}

public int getValue_two() {
    return value_two;
}

public void setValue_two(int value_two) {
    this.value_two = value_two;
}

public double getValue_three() {
    return value_three;
}

public void setValue_three(double value_three) {
    this.value_three = value_three;
}

}
```

Repository interface with the database is defined below:

```
@Repository
public interface ComponentRepository  
    extends JpaRepository<Component, Integer> {
}
```

The business logic is implemented in the service class:

```
@Service
 public class ComponentService {
@Resource
private ComponentRepository compRepository;

@Transactional // this annotaion is
// important for transaction management in the database
public void saveComponents(List<Component> components) {
    int size = components.size();
    int counter = 0;
    List<Component> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Component emp : components) {
        temp.add(emp);
        if ((counter + 1) % 100 == 0
                || (counter + 1) == size) {
            compRepository.saveAll(temp);
            temp.clear();
        }
        counter++;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely using <primitive-array> in the wrong way. Suppose you have an entity called **Player** with the **uniformNumbers** as a property. And you have defined the **uniformNumbers** property as an int array. In order to use <primitive-array> correctly, you will need to define a table for the **Player** entity and an associative table for the **Uniform**.

```
public class Player {
    private int[] uniformNumbers;
}
```

A <primitive-array> element in your mapping allows you to map an array of primitives to an associated table in the database.  **Player** instances are stored in one table, while the associated array of primitives, in this case, **uniformNumbers**, is stored in another table. Each primitive in the array gets its own row in the associated **Uniform** table. Each row is identified by the primitive value and the id of the owning entity, in this case, **Player's** id.  However, when a **Player** is obtained from the database, the entire collection of rows from **Uniform** that are associated to the **Player** (by ID) are used to obtain the array of ints for the **uniformNumbers** property.

```
<class name="Player" table="player">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    ...
    <primitive-array name="uniformNumbers" table="uniform">
        <key column="player_id"/>
        <index column="order"/>
        <element column="uniform_number" type="int"/>
    </primitive-array>
</class>
```

In other words, you will have to define three associated tables. One for each primitive array.